# Resize div border automatically

Tags: html, css

Dears,

I have a `div` with its style. But I just want this `div` to resize automatically depending on the inside text to surround all the text properly.

When I set the `width` to a certain percentage, it will be that size no matter how big is the text, and when the text is long, it will go over the border.

```
<div style="position:relative; width: 60%; height:90%; text-align:center; border:1px solid black; display: inline-block;">
    Some Text.
</div>
```

Please help!

Comment: set width and height to auto

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set width and height to `auto` 
And if you want the div to have a minimum width or height use `min-width` and `min-height`
For example

```
div{
min-width : 200px;
min-height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I suggest this code to try.I set width and height to auto .Because then it will automatically resize to content.

If we put max-width and max-height,It will no resize given width and height value

```
<div style="position:relative; width: auto; height:auto; text-align:center; border:1px solid black; display: inline-block;">
    Some Text.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not set value for height and add more space using padding-top and padding bottom. Div height will expand automatically.